# Is there a way to find the printer name of the printer connected to my android for printing documents?

Tags: java, android, webview, barcode-scanner

Using Android Zebra TC520K scanner . 
I am currently only getting my android to print documents, but I also need to get the name of the printer currently being used.

```
    private void printTheView(String printData) {
        printWebView = new WebView(this);
        printWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                createWebPagePrint(view);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
        printWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, printData, "text/plain", "UTF-8", null);
    }
    public void createWebPagePrint(WebView webView) {
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter("Proof Of Delivery");
        String jobName = "Proof Of Delivery";
        PrintAttributes.Builder builder = new PrintAttributes.Builder();

        builder.setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_LETTER);
        PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, builder.build());
    }
```

Comment: I do not think that information is exposed to developers. You just request the print job; what printer the user chooses is up to the user, and that information is not part of the `PrintJob` API.

Comment: I believe you are correct. Thank you, I appreciate the response!